# How to specify the type for factory objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns, types, factory

I have a model view architecture. I want to create a view object from a model object.
Here is a basic example.

How do i specify the type of my model objects: enums (but then they are not extendable), ints (but then easy to get messed up) ...

```cpp
class ModelA
{
    ModelA(int a);
}

class ModelB : public ModelA
{
    ModelB(int a,int b);
}

class ViewModelA
{
    ViewModelA(ModelA* ma);
}

class ViewModelB : public ViewModelA
{
    ViewModelB(ModelB* mb);
}

class ViewFactory
{
     ModelA * createFromModel(ModelA *ma)
     {
          // Now what is the best way to store type ???
          // Used an integer and overload a static method getType()
          // Or use an enum?
          switch(ma.type)
          {

          }
     }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ModelA *ma = new ModelA(10);
    ModelA *mb = new ModelB(10,11); 
    ViewFactory myFactory;
    ViewModelA *va = myFactory.createFromModel(ma);
    ViewModelB *vb = myFactory.createFromModel(mb);
    //va should be a model of ViewModelA and vb a model of ViewModelB
}
```

Comment: Why not just use polymorphism here, rather than a stored type and a switch statement?  Your `createFromModel` function would just call member functions on the `ModelA` pointer, and the appropriate function would be polymorphically selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, from your question and comment on other answer, you can also use [Visitor pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) here.
Read about it [here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) or [here](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)

So, the model hierarchy would be visited by the `Visitor`.
The responsibility of the `Visitor` will be to create appropriate `View` object for the visited `Model` type.

Then you do not need to store/declare model type.

Working code: Also live here: http://ideone.com/9A5bJ

```
#include <iostream>



class Visitor{
public:
    virtual ~Visitor(){}
    virtual void visitModelA(class ModelA*) = 0;
    virtual void visitModelB(class ModelB*) = 0;
    //add visit functions for later defined models

};





class View{
public:
    virtual ~View(){}
};

class ViewA : public View{
public:
    ViewA(){
        std::cout << "Created ViewA\n"; 
    }
};


class ViewB : public View{
public:
    ViewB(){
        std::cout << "Created ViewB\n"; 
    }
};








class Model{
public:
    virtual ~Model(){}

    virtual void Accept(Visitor* visitor) = 0;

};

class ModelA:public Model{
public:

    virtual void Accept(Visitor* visitor){
        visitor->visitModelA(this);
    }
};

class ModelB:public Model{
public:
    virtual void Accept(Visitor* visitor){
        visitor->visitModelB(this);
    }
};






// ViewCreator can be made a private class of ViewFactory
class ViewCreator : public Visitor{
public:
    virtual void visitModelA(class ModelA*) {
        _view = new ViewA();
    }
    virtual void visitModelB(class ModelB*) {
        _view = new ViewB();
    }

    //add visit functions for later defined models

    View* GetView(){
        return _view;
    }   

private:
    View* _view;
};


class ViewFactory{
public:
    static View* CreateViewFor( Model* model){
        ViewCreator viewCreator;
        model->Accept(&viewCreator);
        return viewCreator.GetView();
    }

};


int main(){

    ModelA modelA;
    View* viewA = ViewFactory::CreateViewFor(&modelA);


    ModelB modelB;
    View* viewB = ViewFactory::CreateViewFor(&modelB);



}
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of overkill for me. Plus i have to add extra data to the model since i have to keep a link to visitor in my model.

Comment: Maybe. You do not need to keep extra data in Model, you do need to add a Accept function().

Comment: Works like a charm. A little drawback is that i have to create a FactoryObject every time i need to create a view object, (since _view can be changed in my multithreaded application), but otherwise works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to help. You could(should?) have the Create() function of Factory as static, thus no need to create FactoryObject.

Comment: Problem comes from View* GetView(). IF you have 2+ threads accessing the object it is possible the first thread creates the _view object. But then a second thread may change _view object before the first one got it. Locking and Unlocking will be a true pain.

Comment: This will not happen in above code since the Visitor i.e. ViewCreator is temp object inside  ViewFactory::CreateViewFor() , so each thread will have its own temp copy of ViewCreator and thus _view

Answer (score 0):

You need interfaces for all types :

```
class ModelIface
{
}
class ModelA : public ModelIface
{
    ModelA(int a);
}

class ModelB : public ModelIface
{
    ModelB(int a,int b);
}

class ViewIface
{
}
class ViewModelA : public ViewIface
{
    ViewModelA(ModelIface* ma);
}

class ViewModelB : public ViewIface
{
    ViewModelB(ModelIface* mb);
}

class ViewFactory
{
     ViewIface * create(ModelIface *ma)
     {
          switch(ma.type)
          {
             case TYPE1:
               return new ViewModelA(ma);
             case TYPE2:
               return new ViewModelB(ma);
             default :
               ;
          }
          return nullptr;
     }
}
```

Whether TYPE1 and TYPE2 are int, or enum is irrelevant.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ModelIface *ma = new ModelA(10);
    ModelIface *mb = new ModelB(10,11); 
    ViewFactory myFactory;
    ViewModelIface *va = myFactory.createFromModel(ma);
    ViewModelIface *vb = myFactory.createFromModel(mb);
    //va should be a model of ViewModelA and vb a model of ViewModelB
}
```

Comment: The thing is if use enum as type, i will have to store it in the base class (in the ModelInterface), so each time i will add a new class to the model hierarchy i will have to modify ModelInterface, and i fear recompilation will be long ...

Comment: @Anton No, why do you need to store it in the base class? You can store it in a separate header, and with c++11 you can use strongly typed enums and enum forward declaration.

Comment: I am not sure MinGW gcc is of c++11 standart, which is why i dont think i can use forward declaration of enums.